# How can I get from La Paz, Bolivia to Puno, Peru?

Tags: transportation, peru, bolivia, la-paz, puno

I'm wanting to travel from La Paz, Bolivia to Puno.  What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Travel SE. Your question is too vague. What means "best" for you? For me the best way would be to call Angelina Jolie and drive with her :)

Answer (score 5):

For most travellers, there's really only one logical way - the bus.  The airport is 50km away in Juliaca, and generally you fly from Lima.

I did this trip by bus back in 2010 - the 'fast' option around the lake, and you [can read my brief bit about it on my blog](http://www.marksmayo.com/2011/04/10/lake-titicaca-puno-peru-and-the-search-for-cuy-begins/).

From the [Article on Wikivoyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Puno):

> Daily buses depart to and from La Paz, Bolivia on two slightly
>   different routes.
>
> **Direct route via Desaguadero (the fastest route, about 5 hours taking shared taxis).**
>
> To do this, take a bus from the terminal or a shared taxi to
>   Desaguadero (2-3 hours, most buses leave before 10am) and after
>   getting your passport stamped on both sides of the bridge, you can
>   take a bus/minivan/shared taxi to La Paz (10/15/25 Bolivianos, 2-3
>   hours, much faster and more comfortable by shared taxi). If you want
>   more space in the back you can pay for an extra seat. Border
>   formalities are quite quick, but you might want to take a bicycle taxi
>   to avoid walking a long way from the bridge to the transport on either
>   side. You can change money here at one of the stalls outside Peruvian
>   immigration - it's best if you know the exchange rate in advance.
>
> **Via ferry boat across Lake Titicaca and Copacabana.**
>
> You should change some money at the border in order to be able to pay
>   the ferry in Bolivianos. Be prepared to change buses in Copacabana.
>   This will mean you will lose your good seats.
>
> When the overnight bus to Cusco stops at the state line for the police
>   to inspect cargo underneath the bus, get out and watch your luggage to
>   avoid theft. Ormeños has buses leaving Puno between 8am and 9am every
>   day. The departure time depends on how long the bus takes to arrive
>   from Lima, so it is necessary to call Ormeños in Puno or Arequipa at
>   about 7am to find out what time the bus will be passing through. The
>   price is 100 Soles per person and the journey should take about 6
>   hours.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the Bus Station in downtown Laz Paz. There are several buses to Peru, most of them will stop in Puno. Just double-check when buying your ticket.

It may be cheaper to take domestic buses and walk across the border but buses around there are so cheap that it is hardly worth the trouble.